# Using two MVC models, in two files

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Inside slider.js:

```
const model = (()=>{})();
const UI = (()=>{})();
const controller = (()=>{})();
```

Inside main.js:

```
const model = (()=>{})();
const UI = (()=>{})();
const controller = (()=>{})();
```

The problem is that javascript is telling me that the constant model has already been declared previously.

so here is what I've tried:

I knew that the problem is happening because the both codes inside those two files are considered inside the global scope,
so I've tried to implement something to keep each file inside a separate scope, so I've tried:

inside slider.js:

```
const slider = ()=>{
    const model = (()=>{})();
    const UI = (()=>{})();
    const controller = (()=>{})();
}
```

and inside main.js

```
const main = ()=>{
    const model = (()=>{})();
    const UI = (()=>{})();
    const controller = (()=>{})();
}
```

but the problem now and I knew that this will happen is that now I can't reach (call) the controller returned methods

Some people will say change the variable names, but I don't think that this is the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slider and main components are self-contained and does not need to be referenced later, you can wrap all the source code inside an anonymous function and all will be good. For example:

```js
(() => {
  const model = (()=>{})();
  const UI = (()=>{})();
  const controller = (()=>{})();
})();
```

However, if you're going to use components in other files, you can do something like the following:

```js
const slider = (()=>{
    const model = (() => 'slider model')();
    const UI = (() => 'slider UI')();
    const controller = (() => 'slider controller')();
    
    return { model, UI, controller };
})();

console.log(slider.controller);
```

## UPDATE

If you only need controller you can just return `controller` in `slider`, e.g.:

```js
const slider = (() => {
  const model = (() => 'slider model')();
  const UI = (() => 'slider UI')();
  const controller = (() => 'slider controller')();

  return controller;
})();

console.log(slider);
```

Comment: I want to call the controller returned methods from the HTML file, for example <button onclick="">

Comment: The second code you added fixes my problem in a very good way, but the bad part is that everytime I want to get into the controller methods I will need to write slider.controller for example <button onclick="slider.controller.move()">

Comment: I think that I can fix this problem by making the controller code inside the global scope, meaning that I will move the code inside  const controller = (() => { this code... to the outer scope, meaning inside slider = (()=>{

Comment: this will help me avoid writing slider.controller each time I want to use the controller methods, so now I will only write <button onclick="slider.move()">

Comment: May I ask what will this code return? return { model, UI, controller };